# Force and Accleration

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, kinematics, acceleration, differentiation

It's just a basic question I had when I was studying physics years back,

So acceleration have two equations

$$a=\frac{F}{m}$$

and

$$a=\frac{\text{d}v}{\text{d}t}$$

So by the first equation, if I'm pushing a wall, the wall does have an acceleration.

But by following the second equation, since velocity is proportional to distance and also because the wall has not moved an inch, the acceleration is zero.

What does this mean actually?

Comment: Whenever you get to an edge case of an ideal situation like an unmovable wall, it's usually wise consider what would really happen. In real life, walls bend ever so slightly when they are pushed, thus they do accelerate! They are also elastic for small displacements, which is how they can push back after the small amount of acceleration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both are perfectly compatible and coherent indeed. If the wall is fixed on the floor your force on the wall, $F$, is counteracted by an equal and opposite force coming from the fixing ground to the wall $-F$. This is Newton's third law. It's important to note that in $F = ma$ (Newton's second law) the force is really the sum of all forces applied to the object in question and the accelleration is really the sum of the accellerations imparted by each force. You can have a huge force as an imput but if the interaction is set in such a way that the reacting force acts on the same object (by fixing the wall to the floor) you end up with both accellerations canceling out just like the two forces (your input force and the response of the floor on the wall) cancel out.

What about a scenario where the wall is not anchored to the floor? Well, it is not true at all that if you have some force $F$, you will notice some accelleration $a = F/m$. That's because the mass of the object $m$ could be gigantic. If the mass is huge your force will produce a tiny accelleration, to the point it might even be undetectable. You need to account for the inertia of the object (its resistance to motion) and not only the force if you want to fully understand what the accelleration would look like (because $a = F/m$ depends both on the $F$ and the $m$).

Comment: +1, but a quick note: inertia is not a resistance to motion, but a resistance to changes in uniform motion (more precisely, resistance to changes in velocity).

Comment: The gist here is correct, but this is *not* Newton's third law-- Newton's third law is universal and has nothing to do with the wall being fixed to the floor. The third law affirms that, as the hand pushes on the wall, so will the wall push on the hand-- this is neither necessary for nor indicative of a force from the ground on the wall. I also think it's quite unphysical to think of each individual force as giving rise to its own acceleration when there is only one observable acceleration, that derived from the net force.

Answer (score 4):

To add to the other correct answers here, I think it's also useful to point out that

$$\mathbf{a} = \frac{\mathbf{F}}{m}$$
is a *dynamical* equation. It describes what the acceleration on a body will experience when there is an external force $\mathbf{F}$. However, the equation $$\mathbf{a} = \frac{\text{d}\mathbf{v}}{\text{d}t}$$

is a *kinematic* equation. It describes how the body will change its instantaneous velocity *due* to this imposed acceleration.

The  kinematic equation is always true, it is the very definition of acceleration. The dynamical equation is true *because* of Newton's Second Law. It is not true in situations where this law does not hold.

In this case, however, Newton's Second Law does indeed hold, but as the other answers have pointed out, the net force on the wall is zero, and hence it has no acceleration and consequently its velocity does not change.